# prove $f + g ∈ Θ(max(f, g))$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, asymptotics

I want to prove $f + g ∈ Θ(max(f, g))$

So I did that $f,g \geq 0$, then $\frac{1}{2}(f+g) \leq \max(f,g) \leq (f+g)$ is equivalent to $ \max(f,g) \leq (f+g) \leq  2 \max(f,g)$.

What if $f \leq 0$ or $g \leq  0$, what can I conclude about $(f + g)$'s time complexity? It seems to be not determinable.

Comment: Could you be more explicit about your actual question? What is exactly that you don't understand about those statements? About your last question, in the context of time complexity it makes no sense that $f$ or $g$ are negative functions, because the time complexity of an algorithm cannot be negative.

Answer (score 1):

You are right.  If $f \ge 0$ and $g \le 0$ you cannot get this conclusion.  (Or any conclusion.)  In fact, you could have $g=-f$ and get $f+g=0$ regardless of how big $f$ is.